# Extract specific values from cell based on array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I want to extract some certain values from a simple `cell-array`, which looks like:

```
CellExample{1} = [1,54,2,3,4]
CellExample{2} = [1,4,1,92,9,0,2]
...
```

And I have an additional array that tells me which element I want to extract from each `Cell` element. The array is as long as the cell:

```
ArrayExample = [2,4,...]
```

Basically, I want an array that says:

```
Solution(1) = CellExample{1}(ArrayExample(1)) = 54
Solution(2) = CellExample{2}(ArrayExample(2)) = 92
```

I have thought of using cellfun, but I have still some troubles using it correctly, e.g.:

```
cellfun(@(x) x{:}(ArrayExample),CellExample,'UniformOutput',false)
```

Comment: Isn't your solution(1) supposed to be 54? or am I missing something?

Comment: `cellfun()` already passes the content of the cell to the anonymous function, hence no need for `{:}`

Comment: Start with a loop, there's nothing *wrong* with using a loop. Have something functional first, worry about making it pretty/efficient later.

Comment: @Oleg, you're right - actually, I just found that out by using the debugger - however, I still can't pass the right values from the array

Comment: @Jonas Now it says 52, not 54...

Comment: @excaza, You're right and I will do that in the future (I should have posted the simple for-loop solution) - but recently I've started using cellfun and I got curious what went wrong...

Comment: Also, refrain from using `Cell` as a variable name.

Comment: @RandomGuy thanks, I'll change it - I thought it made it more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following

```
Cell{1} = [1,54,2,3,4]
Cell{2} = [1,4,1,92,9,0,2]

cellfun(@(x) disp(x), Cell)
```

is equivalent to the loop

```
for ii = 1:numel(Cell)
    disp(Cell{ii})
end
```

that is, `cellfun()` already passes the **content** of each cell to the anonymous function.

However, since you want to pass a **numeric** array as the second input to the anonymous function, and `cellfun()` accepts only `cell()` inputs, you need to use **`arrayfun()`**, which does NOT unpack cell content.

In your case:

```
arrayfun(@(c,pos) c{1}(pos), Cell, Array)
```

and it is equivalent to:

```
for ii = 1:numel(Cell)
    Cell{ii}(Array(ii))
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot for 1) helping me to understand cellfun better and 2) a simple solution that I was looking for.